# gtsummary - excluding specific output

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have some R code where variables have a value of either "Checked" or "Unchecked". gtsummary provides me with totals of the "Checked" and "Unchecked" observations. But I would like to exclude the "Unchecked" values from being displayed. I have tried to filter these values out of the dataframe, but nothing I've tried works. I've supplied the code below as well as an example of the output. Any suggestions?

```
table17a <- select(df, si1_s4_v2___1:si1_s4_v2___6) %>%
  filter(trimws(si1_s4_v2___1) != "Unchecked" |
         trimws(si1_s4_v2___2) != "Unchecked" |
         trimws(si1_s4_v2___3) != "Unchecked" |
         trimws(si1_s4_v2___4) != "Unchecked" |
         trimws(si1_s4_v2___5) != "Unchecked" |
         trimws(si1_s4_v2___6) != "Unchecked") %>%
  tbl_summary(
    label = list(
      si1_s4_v2___1 ~ "Yes, before my training/education",
      si1_s4_v2___2 ~ "Yes, during my training/education",
      si1_s4_v2___3 ~ "Yes, during additional training/education",
      si1_s4_v2___4 ~ "Yes, during practice",
      si1_s4_v2___5 ~ "No",
      si1_s4_v2___6 ~ "I prefer not to answer")
  ) %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ NA)  %>%
  modify_header(label ~ " ") %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ " ") %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 17**") %>%
  bold_labels()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy8O2.png)

Comment: Add this to your `tbl_summary()` call: `value = starts_with("si1_s4_v2___") ~ 'Checked'`. This will make a categorical variable dichotomous and only show the level indicated in the `value` argument.